# Splitting fields and zeros

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we have splitting field $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ where $x_1=-x_2$ and $x_3=-x_4$ we can rewrite it like $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,x_3)$ and then we can multiply $a=x_1x_3$ and rewrite it like $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,a)$. I was wondering can we instead of multiplying $x_1$ and $x_3$, can we take $b=x_1^3$ and then get splitting field $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,b)$?

Comment: The term *splitting field* is used for a given base field and a polynomial with coefficients there.

Comment: Are you asking if $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,x_1^3) = \mathbb{Q}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ given your other hypotheses?